# Setting Min-Date for DateTime picker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), specifically the [No Icon (input field only)](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#no-icon-input-field-only) version.

I am trying to use the [minDate](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate) function so that the user will not be able to enter a date that is before the date that I choose, but I am unable to figure out how to set this up with the no icon version.  I can do this with the icon.

Here is what I have:

**HTML/Razor**

---

```
@{
    var firstDate = new Test.Models.MS();
    using (var db = new UCEntities())
    {
        firstDate = db.MSies.Where(x => x.AID == Model.AId && x.deleted == false).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group date date-search-box" data-mindate="@firstDate.Date">
        @Html.TextBox("date", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "datetimepicker1", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Date"})
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search Date</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**jQuery**

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        minDate: $("#datetimepicker1").data("mindate")
    });
});
```

---

I feel like the `data-mindate` needs to be included in the `@Html.TextBox` overload helper method, but how?

Also I know that doing logic in the view is frowned upon and that I could/should use a View Model, but I just want to test this out first.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I figured this out.  With adding data attributes to razor Html helpers you have to use `_` instead of a `-`.

For example:

```
@Html.TextBox("date", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "datetimepicker1", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Date",data_mindate=firstDate.Date})
```

Instead of:

```
@Html.TextBox("date", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "datetimepicker1", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Date",data-mindate=firstDate.Date})
```